# when I click inside textarea it submits form

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

I create modals using this function

```
 function makeModalEnroll(name, description, i, id) {
     var modal = '<div class="modal fade" id="enroll' + i + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="enrollabel" aria-hidden="true">';
     modal += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">';
     modal += '<div class="modal-content">';
     modal += '<div class="label-success modal-header" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">';
     modal += '<h3><span class="label label-success">Enroll on ' + name + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></h3>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '<div class="modal-body">';
     modal += '<div class="row">';
     modal += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
     modal += '<img data-src="holder.js/200x200">';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">';
     modal += '<form role="form" id="enrollForm' + i + '">';
     modal += '<input type="hidden" name="eventID" id="eventID" value="' + id +'">';
     modal += '<div class="list-group">';
     modal += '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"> <h4><span class="badge">Description:</span> <span class="label label-success pull-right">' +  description + '</span></h4></a>';
     modal += '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"> <h4><span class="badge">Your message</span></h4><textarea id="userMessage" name="userMessage" class="textarea"></textarea></a>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '</form>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '<div class="modal-footer">';
     modal += '<button type="button" id="enroll"' + i + '" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"> Подать заявку <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> </button>';
     modal += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> Закрыть <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </button>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '</div>';
     modal += '</div>';

     return modal;
};
```

Jquery loop where I create modals looks like this

```
$.post("loadallevents.html", function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var k = 0; 
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        k++;
        $("#all_events").append(makeTemplate(item.description, item.eventStatus.name, item.name, k));
        $("#main_container").append(makeModalInfo(item.name, item.description, item.capacity, item.dateTime, item.eventStatus.name, k));
        $("#main_container").append(makeModalEnroll(item.name, item.description, k, item.id));
        $("#tooltip" + k).tooltip();
        $("#enroll" + k).click(function(){
            $("#enrollForm" + k).ajaxSubmit({url: 'enroll.html', type: 'post'});
        });
    });
});
```

The form looks like this
[image]

But when I want to write a message and click inside textarea - it submits form.

Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the form is not realy posting, it is just reloading the page. The problem is, that you nested your textarea inside an "A"-tag:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"> <h4><span class="badge">Your message</span></h4><textarea id="userMessage" name="userMessage" class="textarea"></textarea></a>
```

Remove the link that wraps the textarea and you should be fine:

```
<h4><span class="badge">Your message</span></h4><textarea id="userMessage" name="userMessage" class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Extra: 
I looked into your code after you added the extra script. It seems you bind the click (to make the ajax call) to a ID build like this "enroll + i +" so when the element with that ID is clicked, the form will submit.

You use that ID 2 times in your form. You have a DIV with the classes "Modal fade" that has the same ID as your button. Both ID's are build as "enroll + i +".

Comment: I think href='#' should not reload the page.

Comment: @Anar You are right, but sometimes people think a form is sending when you click a href="#". But in this case it wasn't the solution it seems.

user1432980 Is it possible for you to set up a demo? Or a JSFiddle?

Comment: It sends ajax request to server - I doubt demo is possible. But I'll try experimenting in order to find the solution.

Comment: Yes. It's solved the problem. Damn that dynamic modals. Is there other way to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You have your text area sitting inside an anchor tag. So I guess it's not submitting the form, but just reloading.
And I can also see a bug near

```
<button type="button" id="enroll"' + i + '" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">         
    Подать заявку 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> 
</button>;
```

After enroll, there is an extra double quote.